# Current version getting null while force update the android application

Tags: android, google-play

I have two application on android playstore. I achived force update in one app by using Jsoup library and its working properly.

But in other app its not working. I am getting latest version null.

final Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=agentapp.digitalindiapayment.com.digitalindiapayment").get();

latestVersion = document.getElementsByAttributeValue("itemprop","softwareVersion").first().tex);

Then When I searched I got it below.

App - 1 - Current version showing
[image]

App - 2 - Current version showing not showing.
[image]

I don't know why in one app current version showing and in other app current version not showing on play store because of that i am getting latest version null.

Any one have any idea why the current version not available on play store.

Comment: check your package name in link..

Comment: package name is fine. For this package i am getting version name but for this - com.karnataka.iap package not getting version name

Comment: Did you get any solution for this? I am also getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code as it's working good for me

```
String appStoreVersion  = document.getElementsContainingOwnText("Current Version").parents().first().getAllElements().last().text();
```

Comment: How it will reflect in previous versions

Comment: @Aerrow Google play store page is updated so old method will not work.